# python numpy: iterate for different conditions without using a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I am trying to iterate over numpy arrays and generate an output, which has conditions similar to that described below:

```
min1 = 3
max1 = 1
a1 = np.array([1, 2, 5, 3, 4])
a2 = np.array([5, 2, 6, 2, 1])
output = np.zeros(5)
for i in range(0, 5):
  if((a1[i] - a2[i]) > min1):
    output[i] = 3 * (a1[i] - a2[i])

  if((a1[i] - a2[i]) < max1):
    output = 5 * (a1[i] - a2[i])
```

I need to optimize the above code, so that I utilize the `numpy` functionalities as the best and also avoid using a loop. How should I do it?

Comment: Why you looping here ??

Comment: Not sure why a perfectly functional edit by @Sanober got rejected.  I just manually redid his work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While functions like `select` and `where` can condense the code, I think it's a good idea to know how to do this with basic boolean masking.  It's applicable in many cases, and nearly always as fast.

Calculate the difference which is used several times:

```
In [432]: diff = a1-a2
In [433]: diff
Out[433]: array([-4,  0, -1,  1,  3])
In [435]: output = np.zeros_like(a1)
```

find those cases where it meets the first condition, and set the corresponding elements of `output`:

```
In [436]: mask1 = diff>min1
In [437]: output[mask1] = 3*diff[mask1]
```

repeat for the second condtion:

```
In [438]: mask2 = diff<max1
In [439]: output[mask2] = 5*diff[mask2]
```

and again if there are more conditions.

```
In [440]: output
Out[440]: array([-20,   0,  -5,   0,   0])
```

In this example, only the -4 and -1 met condition 2, and none condition 1.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!  First, a tip for questions:

1. Even your current loopy code doesn't work, as you're assigning values to `output` instead of `output[i]`.  Try to make sure that if you're asking for a code refactor your original code works (and other than `numpy` tags, asking for code refactoring on SO will normally get you downvoted).
2. You're going to want a nested `np.where` statement like this

   ```
   output = np.where((a1 - a2) > min1, 3 * (a1 - a2), (np.where((a1 - a2) < max1, 5 * (a1 - a2), 0)))
   ```

This way you don't need to initialize `output`, and no more loopy code.

If you have lots of conditions, you can also use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
d = a1 - a2
condlist = [d > min1, d < max1]
choicelist = [3 * d, 5 * d]
output = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

Comment: This works too! Thanks! And i'll keep the tips in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. Here's a possible solution depending on what you really want.

This solution will return 2 arrays of that contains values that belong to the min and max that you indicated. What this does is that it does the `-` operation to your two arrays then instead of doing if, numpy has the function called `where` that does this for you without iterating through the whole array.

```
import numpy as np
min1=3
max1=1
a1=np.array([1,2,5,3,4])
a2=np.array([5,2,6,2,1])
array_op = a1-a2
min_output = 3*(array_op[np.where((array_op)>min1)])
max_output = 5*(array_op[np.where((array_op)<max1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
    import numpy as np
    min1=3
    max1=1
    a1=np.array([1,2,5,3,4])
    a2=np.array([5,2,6,2,1])

    output=np.zeros(5)
    diff = a1-a2

    output[np.where(diff < max1)] = diff[np.where(diff < max1)]*5
    output[np.where(diff > min1)] = diff[np.where(diff > min1)]*3
```

Answer (score -1):

The operation a1[i]-a2[i] is done 4 times in a single iteration
Save it as a variable to save 3*5 = 15 computations

Comment: If you don't have a *complete* answer, just leave a comment.  You'll be able to comment once you get enough reputation.