# Change every single element in Numpy object

Tags: numpy

I have a Numpy object with random N*M elements, and I also have two numbers A and B.

Now I want to access every element in this N*M array and make a change, i.e., if the element > 0, replace this element to A (i.e., element <- A), and if this element < 0, replace this element to B (i.e., element <- B).

I know there is a naive way to implement this method, that is accessing every single element using for loop, but it is very slow.

Can we use more fancy code to implement this ?

Comment: Try `numpy.clip`.

Comment: Look at `np.where`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boolean masked assignment will change values in place:

```
In [493]: arr = np.random.randint(-10,10,(5,7))
In [494]: arr
Out[494]: 
array([[ -5,  -6,  -7,  -1,  -8,  -8, -10],
       [ -9,   1,  -3,  -9,   3,   8,  -1],
       [  6,  -7,   4,   0,  -4,   4,  -2],
       [ -3, -10,  -2,   7,  -4,   2,   2],
       [ -5,   5,  -1,  -7,   7,   5,  -7]])
In [495]: arr[arr>0] = 100
In [496]: arr[arr<0] = -50
In [497]: arr
Out[497]: 
array([[-50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50, -50],
       [-50, 100, -50, -50, 100, 100, -50],
       [100, -50, 100,   0, -50, 100, -50],
       [-50, -50, -50, 100, -50, 100, 100],
       [-50, 100, -50, -50, 100, 100, -50]])
```

I just gave a similar answer in

[python numpy: iterate for different conditions without using a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44940806/python-numpy-iterate-for-different-conditions-without-using-a-loop)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
narr = np.random.randint(-100,100,(10,5))
array([[ 70, -20,  96,  73, -94],
       [ 42,  35, -55,  56,  54],
       [ 97, -16,  24,  32,  78],
       [ 49,  49, -11, -82,  82],
       [-10,  59, -42, -68, -70],
       [ 95,  23,  22,  58, -38],
       [ -2, -64,  27, -33, -95],
       [ 98,  42,   8, -83,  85],
       [ 23,  51, -99, -82,  -7],
       [-28, -11, -44,  95,  93]])
A = 1000
B = -999
```

Use `np.where`:

```
np.where(narr > 0, A, np.where(narr < 0, B , narr))
```

Output:

```
array([[1000, -999, 1000, 1000, -999],
       [1000, 1000, -999, 1000, 1000],
       [1000, -999, 1000, 1000, 1000],
       [1000, 1000, -999, -999, 1000],
       [-999, 1000, -999, -999, -999],
       [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, -999],
       [-999, -999, 1000, -999, -999],
       [1000, 1000, 1000, -999, 1000],
       [1000, 1000, -999, -999, -999],
       [-999, -999, -999, 1000, 1000]])
```

Comment: This is helpful ! But the original array narr has not been changed, so I need to allocate new memory to hold this new array. Can we do this change in place?

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned that you're interested in the speed of the computation, I made a speed comparision of several different approaches for your problem.

test.py:

```
import numpy as np

A = 100
B = 50

def createArray():
  array = np.random.randint(-100,100,(500,500))
  return array

def replace(x):
    return A if x > 0 else B

def replace_ForLoop():
    """Simple for-loop."""
    array = createArray()
    for i in range(array.shape[0]):
        for j in range(array.shape[1]):
            array[i][j] = replace(array[i][j])

def replace_nditer():
    """Use numpy.nditer to iterate over values."""
    array = createArray()
    for elem in np.nditer(array, op_flags=['readwrite']):
        elem[...] = replace(elem)

def replace_masks():
    """Use boolean masks."""
    array = createArray()
    array[array>0] = A
    array[array<0] = B

def replace_vectorize():
    """Use numpy.vectorize"""
    array = createArray()
    vectorfunc = np.vectorize(replace)
    array = vectorfunc(array)

def replace_where():
    """Use numpy.where"""
    array = createArray()
    array = np.where(array > 0, A, np.where(array < 0, B , array))
```

Note: The variants using nested for-loops, `np.nditer` and boolean masks work inplace, the last two do not.

**Timing comparision:**

```
> python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.replace_ForLoop()'                     
10 loops, best of 3: 185 msec per loop
> python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.replace_nditer()' 
10 loops, best of 3: 294 msec per loop
> python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.replace_masks()' 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.8 msec per loop
> python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.replace_vectorize()'
10 loops, best of 3: 55.3 msec per loop
> python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.replace_where()'    
100 loops, best of 3: 5.42 msec per loop
```

Using loops is indeed quite slow. `numpy.nditer` is even slower, which comes as a surprise to me, because the doc calls it an [efficient multi-dimensional iterator object to iterate over arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html). `numpy.vectorize` [is essentially a for-loop](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), but still manages to be thrice as fast as the naive implementation.
The `np.where` variant proposed by Scott Boston is slightly faster than using boolean masks as per hpaulj's answer. However, it does need more memory because it does not modify inplace.